# Match, not having a word right before a certain word

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I would like to match the word 'mice' without any words right before it, but my regex isn't working. What am I doing wrong?

```
<?php

$string1 = "one mice";
$string2 = "one .mice";
$string3 = "mice";

if (preg_match("~(?<![a-z]+ )\bmice~", $string1)) { echo "1"; }
if (preg_match("~(?<![a-z]+ )\bmice~", $string2)) { echo "2"; }
if (preg_match("~(?<![a-z]+ )\bmice~", $string3)) { echo "3"; }

?>
```

**Expected Result:**

23

**Actual Result:**

null

I expect it echo 2 because instead of having a word before 'mice', it's a period instead. And I expect it to echo 3 because there's no word before the word 'mice'. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How about enabling `error_reporting` once in a while?

Comment: @mario *raises brows*. There are no error with the code itself. It's just the regex that's written incorrectly, thus the not matching.

Comment: Yes, and the warning tells you how to fix it.

Comment: @mario I don't think error_reporting reports regex errors.

Comment: It very clearly does in your case. -- Afterwards: consider how much specificity your lookbehind really needs.

Comment: @mario ...Is it also counting the word mice as a word to NOT be before the word mice? Is that why it's not matching? So, I have to use (?!mice) to match it?

Comment: @mario Oh wait! I know. Just match for, the word 'mice' not followed by a space!

Comment: PHP preg >= 5.6.11 **does not support infinite repetition inside lookbehind** `(?<![a-z]+ )`, and yes, `error_reporting` would be useful as `php` would warn you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `negative lookbehind` and make the `dot` optional, i.e.:

```
if (preg_match('/(?<![a-z] )\.?\bmice\b/i', $subject)) {
    # Successful match
}
```

---

Regex explanation:

```
(?<![a-z] )\.?\bmice\b

Options: Case insensitive

Assert that it is impossible to match the regex below with the match ending at this position (negative lookbehind) «(?<![a-z] )»
   Match a single character in the range between “a” and “z” (case insensitive) «[a-z]»
   Match the character “ ” literally « »
Match the character “.” literally «\.?»
   Between zero and one times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «?»
Assert position at a word boundary (position preceded or followed—but not both—by a Unicode letter, digit, or underscore) «\b»
Match the character string “mice” literally (case insensitive) «mice»
Assert position at a word boundary (position preceded or followed—but not both—by a Unicode letter, digit, or underscore) «\b»
```

---

[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/uZ1qO0/3)

---

[Ideone Demo](http://ideone.com/rhZsuW)

---

**Note:**

1. PHP preg >= 5.6.11 **does not support infinite repetition inside lookbehind** <strike>`(?<![a-z]+ )`</strike>

Answer (score 0):

```
$string1 = "one mice";
$string2 = "one .mice";
$string3 = "mice";
$regex = "/([^A-z ]|^)mice/";

if (preg_match($regex, $string1)) { echo "1"; }
if (preg_match($regex, $string2)) { echo "2"; }
if (preg_match($regex, $string3)) { echo "3"; }
```

Comment: You should add an explanation of your answer

Answer (score 0):

This `(*SKIP)(*FAIL)` technique will act like a "non-fixed width negative lookbehind" and deliver the same result with fewer required steps than Pedro's (my 133 versus his 221) in my 6-string test case -- see [Pattern Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Iiyvb5/2).

Pattern: `/[a-z]+ mice(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|\bmice\b/`

Code:  ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/4bcd283733a92838584f92fb1cf6a91e21afbf19))

```
$strings=[1=>"one mice",2=>"one .mice",3=>"mice"];
foreach($strings as $i=>$string){
    if(preg_match('/[a-z]+ mice(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|\bmice\b/',$string)){ echo $i;}
}
// output: 23
```